# NGINX Not Resolving Domains

Tags: nginx

I have woken up to an issue this morning where I can access the server via SFTP SSH etc via the IP is fine but if I try and access via the domain I get an error of:

**dev.tinyturtles.co.nz’s server IP address could not be found.**

NGINX Config is sweet and NGINX is started

**UFW Status:**

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
990/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
40000:50000/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
990/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
40000:50000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**NGINX Config:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 64m;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;


    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
      gzip_proxied any;
      gzip_comp_level 2;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
      gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;


    ##
    # Cache Settings
    ##

    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    add_header Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

**Site Config:**

```
fastcgi_cache_path /home/jess/dev.tinyturtles.co.nz/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=dev.domain.co.nz:100m inactive=60m;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.co.nz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.co.nz/privkey.pem;

    server_name dev.tinyturtles.co.nz;

     if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }



    access_log /home/jess/dev.tinyturtles.co.nz/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/jess/dev.tinyturtles.co.nz/logs/error.log;

    root /home/jess/dev.tinyturtles.co.nz/public/;
    index index.php;


    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   

    # Don’t cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   

    # Don’t use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache dev.domain.co.nz;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although Michael gives answer to you particular problem below, I also think it's important you (as a website operator) understand that you went totally wrong about this problem: error your browser was displaying indicated that the browser was not even able to resolve domain name to IP, so your server configuration could not even hypothetically be the reason.

Comment: You have put up quite a lot of security related details on your server configuration, such as open ports in your firewall, and even given us your domain name so we can probe your server. You should consider hardening your security configuration now you have made so much of it public.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your [domain expired](https://dnc.org.nz/whois/search?domain_name=tinyturtles.co.nz) about 12 hours ago.

```
query_status: 210 PendingRelease
domain_dateregistered: 2010-01-25T21:47:09+13:00
domain_datebilleduntil: 2018-02-25T21:47:09+13:00
domain_datelastmodified: 2018-02-25T23:31:23+13:00
domain_datecancelled: 2018-02-25T23:31:23+13:00
```

Contact [your registrar](http://www.affordabledomains.co.nz/) for further instructions on recovering and renewing your domain.